# App Script and Google Sheets - Automated Calendar

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

Super new to App Scripts and Sheets. I'm trying to make an excel sheet where once dates are added / updated they can be synced to a calendar.

I've been following tutorials online but am hitting a few roadblocks.

Whenever I hit the button in my spreadsheet, I get "Script function not found: scheduleEvents"

I'm also trying to figure out how to add an if statement, so not to create duplicates.

Any guidance is very much appreciated,

Thanks!

Code:

````
 function onOpen() {
      var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
      ui.createMenu('Sync to Calendar')
          .addItem('Add Events','scheduleEvents')
          .addToUi();

    function menu() {
      SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
         .alert('Synced');
    }
function scheduleEvents() {

var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().flush;
var calendarId = spreadsheet.getRange("P2").getValue();
var eventCal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarId);

var signups = spreadsheet.getRange("C5:E1000").getValues();
for (x=0; x<signups.length; x++) {

var shift = signups[x];

var startTime = shift[0];
var endTime = shift[1];
var title = shift[2];

eventCal.createEvent(title, startTime, endTime);
}}}```


[Spreadsheet][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wW0S7.png
````

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a reason to nest functions. Keep your functions as top-level, so you won't get the `Script function not found: scheduleEvents` error.

Other issues:

- `const spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().flush;` contains an error. `flush` is a [method](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#flush), not a property, so it should be called: `flush()`. However, you want the variable to point to your spreadsheet.
- Use `const` or `let` instead of `var`.

This is closer to what you want. I can't verify if it works though because I don't know the contents of your sheet.

```js
function onOpen() {
  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Sync to Calendar')
    .addItem('Add Events', 'scheduleEvents')
    .addToUi();
}

function menu() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('Synced');
}

function scheduleEvents() {
   const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   const sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
   SpreadsheetApp.flush();

  const calendarId = sheet.getRange("P2").getValue();
  const eventCal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarId);

  const signups = sheet.getRange("C5:E1000").getValues();

  for (let x = 0; x < signups.length; x++) {

    const shift = signups[x];

    const startTime = shift[0];
    const endTime = shift[1];
    const title = shift[2];

    eventCal.createEvent(title, startTime, endTime);
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey this is awesome and so helpful!!!!  I'm getting this back though: Exception: The parameters (null,(class),String) don't match the method signature for CalendarApp.Calendar.createEvent.

Comment: I've added an image of the spreadsheet to the OP